# Why is my JSON array response returns undefined when I try to access specific value

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp

I would like to get an specific value from nested array returned from AJAX response,
Below is my ajax call from an jsp and have posted the return response below.

```
  $.ajax({

        url: "servletCall.jsp",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"html",
        data: {
        appId:appID,    
        functionalID : functionalID,
         async:false,
            cache: false,
        },
        ContentType:'json',
        success: function(data){

            data = data.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")  
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");

data = data.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]+/g,"");  

 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

// console.log('NOTHINH'+jsonObj) ;
  newString = jsonObj.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');

   // console.log(newString) ;
 alert(newString['functionalSubDomainName']);
 alert(newString['jsonArray2']);
 alert(newString.functionalSubDomainName);

)};
```

newString:JSON response: from the ServletCall.jsp which was later stringfy and parsed

```
{
 "jsonArray2":[
  {
     "pkApplicationid":450.0,
     "success":false,
     "numberOfCustomerUsers":0,
     "numberofCustomers":0,
     "dGFFCorpSecInfo":"",
     "dGFFCorpSecDisas":"",
     "securitycompliancecomment":"",
     "dedicatedFTE":0,
     "noOfCountries":0,
     "noOfCountriesR":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfaces":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfacesR":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfaces":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfacesR":0,
     "totalNoOfUsers":0,
     "totalNoOfUsersR":0,
     "noOfStations":0,
     "productWrite":false,
     "functionalDomainID":1018,
     "functionalDomainName":"Product Operations / Customer Service",
     "functionalSubDomainID":1020,
     "functionalSubDomainName":"VAS-WMS"
  },     
  {
     "pkApplicationid":450.0,
     "success":false,
     "numberOfCustomerUsers":0,
     "numberofCustomers":0,
     "dGFFCorpSecInfo":"",
     "dGFFCorpSecDisas":"",
     "securitycompliancecomment":"",
     "dedicatedFTE":0,
     "noOfCountries":0,
     "noOfCountriesR":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfaces":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfacesR":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfaces":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfacesR":0,
     "totalNoOfUsers":0,
     "totalNoOfUsersR":0,
     "noOfStations":0,
     "productWrite":false,
     "functionalDomainID":1021,
     "functionalDomainName":"Finance",
     "functionalSubDomainID":1049,
     "functionalSubDomainName":"Enterprise Performance Management"
  },      
  {
     "pkApplicationid":450.0,
     "success":false,
     "numberOfCustomerUsers":0,
     "numberofCustomers":0,
     "dGFFCorpSecInfo":"",
     "dGFFCorpSecDisas":"",
     "securitycompliancecomment":"",
     "dedicatedFTE":0,
     "noOfCountries":0,
     "noOfCountriesR":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfaces":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfacesR":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfaces":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfacesR":0,
     "totalNoOfUsers":0,
     "totalNoOfUsersR":0,
     "noOfStations":0,
     "productWrite":false,
     "functionalDomainID":1590,
     "functionalDomainName":"Supporting Applications",
     "functionalSubDomainID":1064,
     "functionalSubDomainName":"Document Logistics"
  },      
  {
     "pkApplicationid":450.0,
     "success":false,
     "numberOfCustomerUsers":0,
     "numberofCustomers":0,
     "dGFFCorpSecInfo":"",
     "dGFFCorpSecDisas":"",
     "securitycompliancecomment":"",
     "dedicatedFTE":0,
     "noOfCountries":0,
     "noOfCountriesR":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfaces":0,
     "noOfA2AInterfacesR":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfaces":0,
     "noOfB2BInterfacesR":0,
     "totalNoOfUsers":0,
     "totalNoOfUsersR":0,
     "noOfStations":0,
     "productWrite":false,
     "functionalDomainID":1590,
     "functionalDomainName":"Supporting Applications",
     "functionalSubDomainID":1392,
     "functionalSubDomainName":"Activity Monitoring and Business Rules"
  }
]
}
```

All my alert returns undefined.
Please help me to resolve.

Comment: Your `success: function(data){...}` should already return a JavaScript object, without you needing to do any additional processing - so you should be able to remove all those `replace()` transformations. Then, you can access the data array like this: `var myArray = data.jsonArray2;`, or like this: `jsonObj["jsonArray2"]`. Then you can iterate over the array in the normal JavaScript way, to access the details of each object in the array.

Comment: Also, you have tagged this question as a `java` question - which is incorrect. You should be using the `javascript` tag instead.

Comment: @andrewjames: It returns an JS Object where im able to print JSON object in console.log.

Comment: Im getting all values printed vertically one word by word if i use this  for(var i in newString ){
   console.log(newString [i]);}

Comment: I recommend you edit your question, show your (updated) code, and show the related output. When I use the following: `console.log(myArray[2].functionalSubDomainName);`, I get a normal string containing "Document Logistics" - all on one line.

Comment: Or, for iteration: `myArray.forEach(function(item){ console.log('func domain name: ' + item.functionalDomainName); });`.

Comment: Please find my complete code with the suggestion added,

Comment: var myArray = newString.jsonArray2;
   console.log(newString);
  console.log(myArray);
  
  /* myArray.forEach(function(item){
   console.log('func domain name: ' + item.functionalDomainName);
   }); */

Comment: Im getting below erro if i add foreach statement,
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.success (appEntry.jsp?mode=Edit&appID=162&serviceID=&moduleParam=INTERFACE_APP_READ:212)
    at c (VM2192 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM2192 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at l (VM2192 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM2192 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)

Comment: Please be kind to let me know how to resolve this

Comment: @andrewjames: Also tried this which returns empty         newString.forEach(function(item){
   console.log('func domain name: ' + item.functionalDomainName);
   });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214072/discussion-between-saranya-and-andrewjames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data  coming from server is already json you don't need to `parse` it again . Also , you can use
`response.jsonArray2[i].yourkeyname` to fetch any data from your json response.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your response
var response = {
  "jsonArray2": [{
      "pkApplicationid": 450.0,
      "success": false,
      "numberOfCustomerUsers": 0,
      "numberofCustomers": 0,
      "dGFFCorpSecInfo": "",
      "dGFFCorpSecDisas": "",
      "securitycompliancecomment": "",
      "dedicatedFTE": 0,
      "noOfCountries": 0,
      "noOfCountriesR": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfacesR": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfacesR": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsers": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsersR": 0,
      "noOfStations": 0,
      "productWrite": false,
      "functionalDomainID": 1018,
      "functionalDomainName": "Product Operations / Customer Service",
      "functionalSubDomainID": 1020,
      "functionalSubDomainName": "VAS-WMS"
    },
    {
      "pkApplicationid": 450.0,
      "success": false,
      "numberOfCustomerUsers": 0,
      "numberofCustomers": 0,
      "dGFFCorpSecInfo": "",
      "dGFFCorpSecDisas": "",
      "securitycompliancecomment": "",
      "dedicatedFTE": 0,
      "noOfCountries": 0,
      "noOfCountriesR": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfacesR": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfacesR": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsers": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsersR": 0,
      "noOfStations": 0,
      "productWrite": false,
      "functionalDomainID": 1021,
      "functionalDomainName": "Finance",
      "functionalSubDomainID": 1049,
      "functionalSubDomainName": "Enterprise Performance Management"
    },
    {
      "pkApplicationid": 450.0,
      "success": false,
      "numberOfCustomerUsers": 0,
      "numberofCustomers": 0,
      "dGFFCorpSecInfo": "",
      "dGFFCorpSecDisas": "",
      "securitycompliancecomment": "",
      "dedicatedFTE": 0,
      "noOfCountries": 0,
      "noOfCountriesR": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfacesR": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfacesR": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsers": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsersR": 0,
      "noOfStations": 0,
      "productWrite": false,
      "functionalDomainID": 1590,
      "functionalDomainName": "Supporting Applications",
      "functionalSubDomainID": 1064,
      "functionalSubDomainName": "Document Logistics"
    },
    {
      "pkApplicationid": 450.0,
      "success": false,
      "numberOfCustomerUsers": 0,
      "numberofCustomers": 0,
      "dGFFCorpSecInfo": "",
      "dGFFCorpSecDisas": "",
      "securitycompliancecomment": "",
      "dedicatedFTE": 0,
      "noOfCountries": 0,
      "noOfCountriesR": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfA2AInterfacesR": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfaces": 0,
      "noOfB2BInterfacesR": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsers": 0,
      "totalNoOfUsersR": 0,
      "noOfStations": 0,
      "productWrite": false,
      "functionalDomainID": 1590,
      "functionalDomainName": "Supporting Applications",
      "functionalSubDomainID": 1392,
      "functionalSubDomainName": "Activity Monitoring and Business Rules"
    }
  ]
};
var new_data = "";
//looping through jsonArray2
for (var i = 0; i < response.jsonArray2.length; i++) {
  //do same for other values also 
  new_data += "pkApplicationid : " + response.jsonArray2[i].pkApplicationid + "  || functionalSubDomainName : " + response.jsonArray2[i].functionalSubDomainName + "<br><br>";
}
//append result to some div
$(".data").html(new_data);

var new_data1 = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Supporting Applications</th></tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < response.jsonArray2.length; i++) {
  //checking against the functionalDomainName if same
  if (response.jsonArray2[i].functionalDomainName === "Supporting Applications") {
    new_data1 += "<tr><td> " + response.jsonArray2[i].functionalSubDomainName + "</td></tr>";
  }
}
name_data1 = "</table>"
//append result to some div
$(".data2").html(new_data1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
</div>
<div class="data2">
</div>
```

Comment: Can u please suggest me how to remove duplicates also from this list..say functionalDomainName="Supporting Applications" if added twice ,in table only one value to be displayed

Comment: THis is because SubDomain is an child..where functionalDomainName is parent..

Comment: How does your table look like ? can you elaborate how you need to show them ?

Comment: Like functionalDomainName:Supporting Application can have functionaSublDomainName: <td>Document Logistics</td><td>Activity Monitoring and Business Rules</td> and so on..But now two Support Application is displayed for each child..

Comment: i have added one example in my answer check and see onces.

Comment: Its very neat and easy understandable for beginners like me..GREAT!!!Many thanks :)